# Home page of visually-hidden?

Tags: css

I can't find it on GitHub. Where does the pattern live and grow? I found at least 10+ it's versions, Including: [Click to see an Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTfa7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.visually-hidden` and its properties are a documented CSS **pattern** versus a maintained project by any single source. You can find references to it in this 2011 [snook.ca article](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility) as `.element-invisible`, this 2015 [The A11Y Project article](https://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content/) as `.visually-hidden`, and HTML5 Boilderplate project [here](https://github.com/h5bp/main.css/blob/master/src/_helpers.css) as `.visuallyhidden`.

I believe the Snook.ca article is the first source of this variation of the pattern.

The exact syntax and formatting are a bit different between each reference, but the properties are mostly the same with the exception of some minor differences such as the H5BP project removing legacy Internet Explorer support.

I don't have an exact number, but I am sure this code or variations of it show up in dozens, if not hundreds, of projects.